# Django, PostgreSQL и часовые пояса

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Запутались в настройке проекта и часовых поясах.
Имеем следующие настройки для дат.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Ожидаем, что в БД дата будет храниться в формате UTС, но с сохранением часового пояса.

Т.е. в бд (по нашему мнению) должно быть

`2019-02-26 06:16:47.212351 +03:00`

а не

`2019-02-26 06:16:47.212351 +00:00`

Вообще мы понимаем, что работать всегда лучше с UTC. Но, например, `celery` задачи мы запускаем по Москве.

Как получить ожидаемое поведение? Или мы не в ту сторону думаем? Как приводить UTC дату к Москве если нужно?

```
>>> from project.apps.orders.models.Order import Order
>>> o = Order.objects.get(pk=3)
>>> o.date_created
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 26, 6, 16, 47, 212351, tzinfo=<UTC>)
>>> import pytz
>>> pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow").localize(c.date_created)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/blohinn/PycharmProjects/venvs/Project/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 318, in localize
    raise ValueError('Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)')
ValueError: Not naive datetime (tzinfo is already set)
```

Comment: UTC — это **только** `+00:00`, по определению, поэтому никакого `+03:00` в базе быть в принципе не может.

Comment: Преобразуйте время запуска задач из Москвы в UTC и по полученному UTC-времени запускайте

Comment: Крайне советую потратить время и прочитать статью https://ru.hinty.io/ivictbor/django-timezone-chasovye-poiasa-i-vremia-na-prostykh-primerakh/ - Тут все что нужно зноать чтобы перестроить ваш метод правильным образом